# How to select data from a specific user using INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select data from a specific user. When he is logged in on the website he will see information related to him.

I'm using INNER JOIN and I need to select data related to his login or id.

Any account that I use to login, I can access all exercises registered =/

On this case I'm using an ID.

Is something wrong with the query?

I don't get any errors from PHP. Where can I put the WHERE clause?

Code:

```
<?php

$login  = $_SESSION['login'];

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT exercicios.nome_exercicio AS nome_exc,
    exercicios.repeticoes_exercicio AS rep_exc,
    exercicios.serie_exercicio AS serie_exc
    FROM exercicios
    INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id_usuario = exercicios.id_usuario WHERE exercicios.id_usuario = '5'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)> 0){

    echo "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-responsive'>
    <tr><td>Nome</td><td>Repetições</td><td>Série</td></tr>";

    while ($exercicio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta))
    {
        print"<tr>
            <td>$exercicio[nome_exc]</td>
            <td>$exercicio[rep_exc]</td>
            <td>$exercicio[serie_exc]</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo " </table></div>";
}
else {
    echo "<h3>Seu instrutor ainda não cadastrou exercícios</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're only selecting columns from exercicios, so it looks like you don't actually need to join it to usuarios for this to work.

Comment: That being said, it should still work with it joined, and your WHERE clause is not in the wrong place. I really don't see anything wrong with it. Are you sure you have a user with id_usuario=5?

Comment: Yeah -- I was going to say, this looks good to me. I'm wondering if you have something in your `usuarios` table that you want filter on using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hi there. Have you checked if you have a registry to the user id `'5'` ? You are, as already said, filtering by the user id that is already on the table `exercicios` so you don't need the join at all, just take it out. My guess is that the table `exercicios` doesn't have a registry for the user id=5. My second guess is that it should be `exercicios.id_usuario = $login`

Comment: Since you hardcoded the user id on the query.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that _every exercise_ shows up regardless of which user is logged in?

Comment: I was assuming he hardcoded in the user id for testing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @DavidWyly It is a common mistake for starters (forget hardcoded values) so, it could be his problem. Since exercicios table has the column user_id he doesn't need the join at all, just filter by it. Assuming that $login variable is the id

Comment: @JorgeCampos not knowing his database structure, it's hard to say. As an aside, I wish SO had better formatting for database table structure.

Comment: @DavidWyly I guess that since his columns is in portuguese it was easy to me to understand his table structure: `id_usuario` would be the `user_id` :)

Comment: I want to thanks everyone that helped me. The solution was simple: Get data related to user using his id. So I put his id on a session and called on query. Now I have data related to the user. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missed some important things, for example, what data are you storing in your session variable login?

```
$login  = $_SESSION['login'];
```

When a user send the login data first time (for example email and password), you will search the data on the database (table accounts or users or the table you need) and then if exist you should store the user data on session (the id is the most important). So, when you need to access to the exercises of the user, you need only to specify the correct user id on the where condition like ($login in this example is an array with user data):

```
"SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE id = {$login['userId']}"
```

Hope this explanation will be enough to fix your problem.

Comment: I want to thanks everyone that helped me. The solution was simple: Get data related to user using his id. So I put his id on a session and called on query. Now I have data related to the user. Thanks!!